# Is the following always True?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Let $a, b \in Z$ and $n \in N$ . Is the following necessarily true?
If $a^3 ≡b^3$(mod n) then $a ≡ b$ (mod n)

How do I do this?

For the record, I do not think this is True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Try $n=8$ and $a=2$; I’ll let you find an appropriate $b$.

Comment: I guess i dont understand mod then.. because I dont see it.

Comment: @osomabinla: What’s $2^3\bmod 8$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Equivalently, need $\rm\ n\mid \color{#c00}{a-b}\ $ if $\rm\ n\mid a^3-b^3 = (\color{#c00}{a-b})(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: Nice to see the characteristic font again!